# Replicating PostgreSQL data for analytics

Tags: database, postgresql, analytics

I'm currently scoping out at a potential development project where we will develop an analytical solution to support a production application. Obviously we want to run queries on reasonably up-to-date data, but we don't want the operational risk of querying the main database directly with (possibly expensive) analytical queries.

To do this I believe we would like to do the following:

- Make a replica of a "production" PostgreSQL database into a separate "analytics" database
- Add additional tables / views etc to the "analytics" database, which will support the analytics solution only and *not* be part of the application DB.
- Maintain the replica copy of the production data in a reasonably up-to-date fashion (realtime replication not strictly needed, but no more than a few seconds lag would be good)

The database will not be excessively large (it is a web/mobile application with a lot of users but most not likely to be active at any one time).

Is this likely to be feasible with PostgreSQL, and if so what is the best strategy / replication technique to use?

Comment: did you find a better answer? can you expand on your experience after 1 year of going with a solution? how many TB of data?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use [streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) for that, because you cannot add tables to a read-only database. But you might rethink the requirement to not add the additional tables to the production database.

However, there are other replication techniques like [Slony](http://www.slony.info/), [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [Londiste](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Londiste_Tutorial).

One thing that you should keep in mind is that a data model that is suitable for an online transaction processing database is usually not well suited for analytical applications, and you might end up being pretty unhappy with the performance of your analytical queries. For these, the normal thing to do is to build some sort of [*data warehouse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) where data are stored in a more denormalized form, usually in something like a [*star schema*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

But for that you cannot have “no more than a few seconds lag”. Double check if that is really essential, it usually isn't for analytical queries.

Comment: pglogical or BDR could also be options

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected that might be the case. Well aware that the raw data tables are not good for analytical queries (that is the main reason for the extra tables....)